# Filter array of objects by sub array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
movies = [{'title': 'a', 'genres': ['Romance', 'Comedy']}, 
          {'title': 'b', 'genres': ['Drama', 'Comedy']}, 
          {'title': 'c', 'genres': ['Action', 'Adventure']}]

filters = ['Romance', 'Drama']
```

Desired contents of filtered array:

```
[{'title': 'a', 'genres': ['Romance', 'Comedy']}, 
 {'title': 'b', 'genres': ['Drama', 'Comedy']}]
```

The issue is that I am not sure how to filter an array given another array of values. If 'filters' was just a single string, then I could just do:

```
movies.filter(x => x.genres.includes(filters))
```

But this obviously won't  work if filters is an array of values.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `array.some()` in the filter function to test if any of the genres match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're very close. It looks like what you need is the array `.some` method. That method will return true if it's callback is true for any item, so what you need is for "some" genre to be included in the filter list:

```js
movies = [{
    'title': 'a',
    'genres': ['Romance', 'Comedy']
  },
  {
    'title': 'b',
    'genres': ['Drama', 'Comedy']
  },
  {
    'title': 'c',
    'genres': ['Action', 'Adventure']
  }
]

filters = ['Romance', 'Drama']

//[{'title': 'a', 'genres': ['Romance', 'Comedy']}, 
// {'title': 'b', 'genres': ['Drama', 'Comedy']}]

console.log(movies.filter(x => x.genres.some(g => filters.includes(g))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had actually asked the question incorrectly and wanted to filter where every item in `tags` intersects with a movie's genre, but your answer led me in the right direction. 

This is what I came up with in case it helps anyone else:

`movies.filter(x => tags.every(y => x.genres.includes(y)))`